# Same bitmap to different pictureboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Is there any problem with using a same bitmap for different picture boxes or is it better to create a new bitmap for each picture box from the same stream?

```
picbox1.Image = new Bitmap(myStream);
picbox2.Image = new Bitmap(myStream);
picbox3.Image = new Bitmap(myStream);

or 

var myBitmap = new Bitmap(myStream)
picbox1.Image = myBitmap;
picbox2.Image = myBitmap;
picbox3.Image = myBitmap;
```

Thanks

Comment: As Bitmaps use system resources - the [Bitmap class "Encapsulates a GDI+ bitmap"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) - then you should reuse them where possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are to use the exact same bitmap in each picturebox, I think it's best to use the same bitmap object as well. That seems to be the most efficient way to do it.